# how to convert legacy query to ActiveRecord Rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query in my code as below

```
@sqladdpayment = "INSERT INTO payments (orderid, ttlprodcost, paytype, 
paystatus,created_at,updated_at,userid,storeid) 
VALUES ('" + session[:ordersid] + "', '" + session[:totalcost] + "', '"  
+ "1"+ "', '"  + "complete" +"',current_date, current_date, '"+"1"+"','"+   "1"+"')"
```

Here the table `payments` and primary key is `orderid`.  Now, I know if I convert this to the `ActiveRecord` way then I will not have to put `update_date`, `current_date` because it will put that on it's own.  It will also put `orderid` on it's own also (`auto_increment`).

I am looking for a way to convert the above query to `ActiveRecord` Rails way but still be able to put `orderid` on my own (`session[:ordersid]`).  I do not want to rely on `auto_increment` because then I will have to refactor lot of the other code.  This might be a quick and dirty fix but I want to know whether this type of flexibility is offered in rails?

I have wondered about this question many times. Why won't rails allow me to have that flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to go to a lot of trouble, or maybe i am missing something.
The ActiveRecord way of doing thing is, imho either manually

```
payment = Payments.new
payment.orderid = session[:ordersid]
payment.totalcost = session[:totalcost]
payment.paytype = 1
payment.paystatus = "complete"
payment.userid = 1
payment.storeid = 1
payment.save
```

Now, if you have a form filling up these fields, it is even easier:

```
payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
payment.save
```

So there is no need for an autoincrement field. If you specified that `ordersid' is the id, you can still set the value manually, which will overrule the rails standard behaviour (unless you defined the field to be autoincrement inside the database).

For instance: [an article](http://ariejan.net/2008/08/12/ruby-on-rails-uuid-as-your-activerecord-primary-key/) showing how to use uuids instead of autoincrement.

I do have a remark, when i see this code. Normally for `userid` and `storeid` one would use the inherent relational capabilities built into rails.
For instance, if a payment is related to a user, you either do

```
user.payments.build(params[:payment])
```

and then the newly created payment is automatically linked to the user.
Or

```
payment.user = current_user
```

if you would have something like

```
belongs_to :user
```

in your model.
Maybe you are aware of all that already, that is hard to make up from your question.